# how to set shortcut for add to photos command

Tags: macos

I want to set shortcut for this command. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: I'm usually pretty good at getting this type of service into a key command... but can't figure this one out. Hope you get an answer; would be interesting to see how it's done.